# Конвертация PDF -> HTML -> WORD (docx)

Tags: java, html, pdf

Нужно преобразовать PDF в word. поскольку нужно сохранить форматирование, то пытаюсь сделать через цепочку

pdf->html->word

вот класс

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.FormattingOption;
import org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.NumberingDefinitionsPart;
import org.docx4j.wml.RFonts;
import org.fit.pdfdom.PDFDomTree;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


public class Test{

    private static String filePathPDF = "C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\1.pdf";
    private static String filePathHTML = "C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\1.html";
    private static String filePathDocx = "C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\v2.docx";


    public void xhtmlToDocx(WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage) throws Docx4JException, JAXBException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

        // использую примеры этой библиотеки
        // https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples

        PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(filePathPDF));
        Writer outputPdf = new PrintWriter(filePathHTML, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        new PDFDomTree().writeText(pdf, outputPdf);
        
        String stringFromFile = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(filePathHTML), "UTF-8");

        NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
        ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();
        RFonts rfonts = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createRFonts();
        rfonts.setAscii("Century Gothic");
        XHTMLImporterImpl.addFontMapping("Century Gothic", rfonts);
        XHTMLImporterImpl xHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
        xHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
        xHTMLImporter.setTableFormatting(FormattingOption.IGNORE_CLASS);
        
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(xHTMLImporter.convert(stringFromFile, null));
        wordMLPackage.save(new File(filePathDocx));

    }
}
```

сам html файл получается нормально. т.е форматирование сохраняется. Но итоговый word файл теряется форматирование и получается каша. Причем рисунки, логотипы в итоговом word файле сохраняются, но не на своих местах.